# Is there some way to prove the imaginary part of any complex function is even or odd function?

Tags: complex-analysis, even-and-odd-functions

I have a complex function as f(x) = g(x) + I h(x). 
Because f(x) is very complicated function and depend on some parameter.
I want to know whether there is a way to prove that g(x) or h(x) is even function or odd function???
I checked numerically, the pictures show that g(x) is even function and h(x) is odd function.
Then I guess function h(x) and g(x) has that characters.

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you not just separate out $f(x)$ into real and imaginary parts, write down $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ explicitly and then test to see if they're odd or even? A function $f$ is odd if $f(x) = -f(-x)$ and even if $f(x) = f(-x)$.

Comment: You will have to reveal how $f$ (or $g$ or $h$) is _defined_. Otherwise, we have no way we can tell whether they are even/odd or not, and how that can be proved.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. However my function including square roots and tangential hyperbolic. I can't separate imaginary and real part.

Comment: $2g=f+\bar f$ and similarly for $h$, may help

Comment: Thank you very much @Conrad